# Which design pattern is better to work with Controllers/Services/DAOs

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns

During my career I saw few different designs, how to work with `DAO`, `Service`, `Controller` layers. I want to ask about two, which are similar but have few differences.
First design creates visible barrier between layers. Controllers always use services and only services. Services can use other services or `DAO`s. 
Controllers can't use any `DAO` directly. This design is clear, but has big disadvantage for me: we always have to create method in service for each method in `DAO`.
But in a lot of cases `Service` methods invoke only `DAO`s methods and anything else.

For example:
We have `UserDao`

```
class UserDao {
    public List<User> findByName(String name) { ... }
    public List<User> findByLastName(String name) { ... }
    public List<User> findOlderThan(int age) { ... }

    ......
}
```

All above methods are used by `Controllers`. What we should do in our case? Create similar methods in `UserService`:

```
class UserService {
    public List<User> findByName(String name) { return userDao.findByName(name); }
    public List<User> findByLastName(String name) { return userDao.findByLastName(name); }
    public List<User> findOlderThan(int age) { return userDao.findOlderThan(age); }

    ......
}
```

For me this is additional unnecessary layer for read-only methods.

In second design we do not have a problem with this because we can use DAOs directly in Controllers.
In this design we have a rule: if we want to retrieve a data from "data store" we can use `DAO` in any layer, if we want to make some changes in "data store" we have to use service methods.

What do you think, guys, about these designs? Which is better? Which I should use in my projects and which should be forgotten? Could you share with me yours experience in this sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services, in MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns are the "top part" of the model layer. It's how presentation layer interacts with domain business logic (also, the "reading" part should be done by view instances, actually).

In such structure the services act as a barrier, that isolates presentation layer and gives you additional freedom in altering the internal structure of model later.

Another thing that you have to keep in mind is that there are more structures then just [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)s that services interact with. First of all there are [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) (business objects, model objects) which encapsulate the different business rules that relate to one particular entity. Then you also can have [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), which abstract the storage logic instead of DAOs. Or DAOs that translate information between mappers and domain objects. In larger scale application would would also have [unit(s) of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). In smaller scale you would be fine with some [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) instances.

You could say that model layer contains three main groups of structure where the implement separate aspects of model: domain, storage and application logic.

The application logic is the interaction between storage structures domain objects. That is what services are responsible for.

If you expose DAO, your model layer starts leak in the presentation. Controller should have no idea about what structures are used, and when they are persisted.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. "If you expose DAO, your model layer starts leak in the presentation." - I think this is a big pros for first design and huge cons for second.

Comment: @tereško So why not just inject entityManager into Service? Isn't entityManager a dao itself, which is suitable in CRUD / one resource operations?

Comment: @MGorgon aside from it being a java-specific thing, well ..  entity manager is not a DAO, but another layer of abstraction for persistence. Which means, that you question makes no sense. DAOs are not part of persistence.

Comment: @tereško Isn't Entity Manager implementation of Domain Store? Why hide Domain Store behind DAO?